# How to handle Error: ngModel:datefmt Model is not a date object

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, html, date

I am using angularjs in my project. I am getting date string from back end. Date string can be any string which may be a date or may not be date. When I set the date string to `ng-model` if it's a date string then it's working fine else it throws an exception

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ngModel/datefmt?p0=asdfdaf
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:167:250)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:264:75)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:132:124)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:135:269)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:19:437
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:39:156)
    at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:19:358)
    at Ac (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:20:151)
```

I don't know how to handle this exception. I am thinking about writing a method like `isDate(dateString)` but I don't know what should I write inside it cause date string can be any string in any format. Please help, I have created [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yBnzg9H1ZQlAx7YwRrn2?p=preview)

Comment: I had this problem a time ago, do you mind about crossbrowser compatibility? Check your plunker in Firefox, Chrome and Safari...

Comment: I am targating only chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your input is set to type date, angularJS will only accept Date objects in Javascript.

But, when your input has a type="date", chrome has a special feature that renders that properly, but that is not the case of other browsers.

The solution is to use a string... and convert it

Comment: You can use string, which returns Date object when it is passed to Date constructor.

Comment: In fact, in my case, it depends if you need a lot of interaction with the date (user and logic)

Comment: yeah agreed, it is always preferred to have single type for one value.

Comment: can you please write a method to convert into date object.

Comment: What is the date format your backend is giving you?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a custom method like this

```
function isValidDate(date) {
  return !! (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === "[object Date]" && +date);
}
```

There is a description for your error in angular site

> All date-related inputs like  require the model to
>   be a Date object. If the model is something else, this error will be
>   thrown. Angular does not set validation errors on the  in this
>   case as those errors are shown to the user, but the erroneous state
>   was caused by incorrect application logic and not by the user.

It means that, if you are using type="date" then your ng-model should be Date object or some string value which can be converted to Date object.

Comment: it's returning `false` for string `10/31/1997 23:00`. As I told you string can be any string. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: this is your custom string. You can have custom method which can convert your string to JavaScript Date object. Angular can not understand your date string.

Comment: can you suggest me one method for this type of string, I am new to all these stuff.

Comment: check http://plnkr.co/edit/7rNmZiyvjXBWYsWnO6sw?p=preview. I have create a method which will convert your string to date object.